# Send user input from NodeJS to shell script

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

I have this NodeJS script:

```
var util  = require('util'),
process = require('child_process'),
ls    = process.exec('test.sh');

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
   console.log(data.toString());
   ls.stdin.write('Test');
});
```

and this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please input your name:";
read name;                 
echo "Your name is $name";
```

I tried to run the NodeJS script and it stucked at "Please input your name:". Does anyone know how to send an input from NodeJS script to the shell script ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try adding `'\n'` to the end of your input (e.g. `ls.stdin.write('Test\n');`) to simulate pressing return/enter?

Also, you want `process.spawn`, not `process.exec`. The latter does not have a streaming interface like you are using, but it instead executes the command and buffers stdout and stderr output (passing it to the callback given to `process.exec()`).

Answer (score 5):

You will have to say something like this:

```
ls.stdin.write('test\n');
```

OR

you can inherit standard streams if you want input from user using `spawn`.

like this:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('sh',['test.sh'], { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

Comment: cannot stress enough how thankful I am because of your response of 'inherit'... Thanks a lot

Comment: This answer with the stdio inheritance saved me from a 3 days headache, thank you!!

Comment: stdio: 'inherit' did it! Thanks a lot!